# PHP Parse Error on `for` loop

Tags: php

I'm probably just doing something stupid here, but I can't see the cause of the error.  I'm getting a Parse error on a for loop in a pagination function I'm writing in PHP; heres the full error.

```
PHP Parse error:  parse error, expecting `')'' in /Users/danielsgroves/Sites/Gouland/search.php on line 95
```

And the full function that the error is occurring in is as follows:

```
private function pagination($scope, $keyword)
{
    $pages = 15;

    $pagination = '<ul>';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $pages; i++) {
        $pagination .= "<li><a id=\"a$i\" class=\"na\" href=\"?q=$keyword&scope=$scope&page=$i\">$i</a></li>";
    }
    $pagination .= '</ul>';

    return $pagination;
}
```

As you may have already established from what I said the line 95 mentioned on the error is `for ($i = 0; $` etc.  The full class file is below. I've included the commenting just incase it helps.

```
Class BingSearch
{
private $APPID      = "SOME API KEY";

private $keyword;
private $scope;
private $page;
private $count;
private $offset;

private $response;
private $results;

/**
 * Set the object up with required information to perform the search. Once 
 * the object is setup the getResults() method should be called to display
 * the results where required. 
 * @param (String) $keyword = The search string
 * @param (String) $scope = The scope of the search; web, ticket, image, 
 * video, news
 * @param (Int) $page = The required results page.
 * @public
 */
public function __construct($keyword, $scope, $page)
{
    $this->keyword  = urlencode($keyword);
    $this->scope    = $scope;
    $this->page     = $page;
}

/**
 * Runs the necessary internal methods to fetch and display the required 
 * results.  Required information should be provided into the constructor 
 * on object creation.  This function will not return any information,
 * but 'echo' is straight out onto the page. Each returned result will
 * be placed inside it's own HTML5 <article> tag.  Simply call this 
 * method from the location in your templates of where you would like
 * the search results to be placed.  
 * @public
 */
public function getResults()
{
    $this->fetchFeed();
    $this->generateWebResults();
}

/**
 * Fetches the JSON feed from the Google bing API.  Uses private class
 * variables for the required information. 
 * @private
 */
private function fetchFeed()
{
    $request        = "http://api.search.live.net/json.aspx?Appid=$this->APPID&query=$this->keyword&sources=$this->scope&$this->count&$this->offset";
    $this->response = file_get_contents($request);
    $this->results = json_decode($this->response);
}

/**
 * Formats the returned JSON feed by adapting it for HTML. Each result is 
 * placed within an <article> tag.  The title is an <h3> which also links
 * to the actual result. <span class="cached"> is the cache link and 
 * the description is placed within a <p>.  Finally, <span class="fullLink">
 * contains the URL for the content, which is also linked.  
 * @private
 */
private function generateWebResults()
{
    if($this->results->SearchResponse->Web->Total != 0) {   

        foreach($this->results->SearchResponse->Web->Results as $value) {

            if (!isset($value->Description))
                $value->Description = '';

            echo "<article>";
            echo "<h3><a href=\"$value->Url\" title=\"Go to $value->Title\">$value->Title</a></h3>";
            echo "<span class=\"cached\"><a href=\"$value->CacheUrl\" title=\"View Cached Version\">Cached</a></span>";
            echo "<p>" . strip_tags($value->Description) . "</p>";
            echo "<span class=\"fullLink\"><a href=\"$value->Url\" title=\"Go to $value->Title\">$value->Url</a></span>";
            echo "</article>";

        }

    }
}

private function pagination($scope, $keyword)
{
    $pages = 15;

    $pagination = '<ul>';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $pages; i++) {
        $pagination .= "<li><a id=\"a$i\" class=\"na\" href=\"?q=$keyword&scope=$scope&page=$i\">$i</a></li>";
    }
    $pagination .= '</ul>';

    return $pagination;
}
}
```

To use the function this is the PHP that is run.

```
require 'search.php';
$search = new BingSearch($query, $source, $query);
$search->getResults();
```

Does anyone fancy pointing me in the right direction, it's probably something really small that I've just missed after looking at it for too long.

Thanks,

Dan.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $pages; i++)
```

You forgot a $, replace i++ with $i++.

Comment: Thanks so much, knew it would be something trivial like that!

Answer (score 2):

Your loop

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $pages; i++) {
        $pagination .= "<li><a id=\"a$i\" class=\"na\" href=\"?q=$keyword&scope=$scope&page=$i\">$i</a></li>";
    }
```

You have missed a $ in your loop

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $pages; $i++) {
        $pagination .= "<li><a id=\"a$i\" class=\"na\" href=\"?q=$keyword&scope=$scope&page=$i\">$i</a></li>";
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You forgot the dollar sign for incrementing `$i`.

```
private function pagination($scope, $keyword)
{
    $pages = 15;

    $pagination = '<ul>';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $pages; $i++) {
        $pagination .= "<li><a id=\"a$i\" class=\"na\" href=\"?q=$keyword&scope=$scope&page=$i\">$i</a></li>";
    }
    $pagination .= '</ul>';

    return $pagination;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In that line, replace `i++` with `$i++`. It is missing the $ character.